# Postgres: Is there a way to find rows that don't contain duplicate values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a simple way to achieve the following.

I have a table with 3 columns, `hash`, `signal_key` and `signal`. Previously `signal_key` was an object like so:

```
{
    "entities": [
       {"type": "MERCHANT", "value": "000000008769252"}, 
       {"type": "MERCHANT", "value": "5499"}], 
    "signalType": "TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_OVERRIDE", 
    "signalVersion": "0"
}
```

I ran a migration script on these columns so now the above `signal_key` would be this (updated entities.type and signalVersion):

```
{
     "entities": [
        {"type": "MERCHANT_ID", "value": "000000008769252"}], 
        {"type": "MERCHANT_CATEGORY_CODE", "value": "5499"}, 
     "signalType": "TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_OVERRIDE", 
     "signalVersion": "1"
}
```

However, after running the migration I now have 193 rows with `"signalVersion": "0"` and 189 rows with `"signalVersion": "1"`. Is there a way in postgres to figure out which rows weren't duplicated with the updated values (maybe by looking at entity values etc.)?

Comment: It would be a bit easier to grasp your problem with a data sample and the expected results. cheers

Comment: Are you looking for a sample with all 3 columns populated?